# Appending to <td> instead of below <tr>. What's wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/littlesandra88/tZqYX/

would I like that a new `<tr>` is inserted below the one where "Details" is clicked.

I do

```
$('.row').append("<tr><td>It worked</td></tr>");
```

but this results in

```
<tr class="row">
  <td class="edit-column"><a href="javascript:addRemove('7249');">Details</a> <input value="Save" type="submit"></td>
<tr><td>It worked</td></tr></tr>
```

where I was hoping for

```
<tr class="row">
  <td class="edit-column"><a href="javascript:addRemove('7249');">Details</a> <input value="Save" type="submit"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>It worked</td></tr>
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `$('.row').after("<tr><td>It worked</td></tr>");`

`.append.` is appending the row to the .row row. Using `.after` will put the row AFTER the .row row

Comment: okay. Very interesting! =) it worked, but it is inserted below all the rows, and not just the current. Can this is solved without adding an ID? Maybe somehow with `$(this)`?

Comment: You'll need to pass the element you clicked to the function, then in the function find out which `.row` you are dealing with, then add the row to that `.row`

Answer (score 2):

Try `.after()` instead of `.append()`

```
$('.row').after("<tr><td>It worked</td></tr>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are basically trying to add to an existing row.  You need to add the new row to the table.  Or try something like the next $row after it.

Answer (score 1):

Try `.after()` instead. .append() is for sticking something INSIDE the specified element at the end of the child list

Answer (score 0):

```
$(<tr><td>It worked</td></tr>").insertAfter($('.row'));
```

Comment: Am am getting a very strange error this this one. Its says the function `addRemove` isn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the new row to the `tbody` element, not to the row itself

Answer (score 0):

You are basically trying to add to an existing row.  You need to add the new row to the table.  Or try something like the next $row after it.

```
$('#accTable').append("<tr><td>It worked</td></tr>");
```

Answer (score -1):

The `.after()` is probably what you're looking for. It will append the text after the `row` element.